# Finding 74hc595 alternatives with the same timing- how to read datasheets?

Tags: shift-register

I am a tinkerer trying to find a higher power alternative to the sn74hc595 and my search brought me across the tpic6b595. From googling around a bit I found that the tpic6b595 should work with the existing arduino library. That's fine and I am willing to accept that, but how would I be able to come to that conclusion by looking at the data sheets? I am sure it has something to do with timing, but I keep staring at the datasheets and can't really find any patterns or anything to work with. Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction?

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6b595.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf

Answer (score 2):

First check the functional specifications. They are both output shift regeisters with an attached storage register/latch, so the 'broad' function is the same (but the tpic has pull outputs, versus push-pull for the hc!).

So check the functional details: type and polarity of inputs (and outputs), edges on which the action happens, etc.

I very much doubt that an Arduino (Uno at 16 MHz) could do anything fast enough to violate a timing requirement of these chips. (But a Due at 96 MHz might.)

Comment: From my understanding the 74hc595 shifts in whatever bit is on the data line whenever the clock line goes from low to high? So do all Shift Registers shift in bits this same way and do you only really need to make sure that you are not shifting in bits too quickly? There is no other patterns or timing that matters? @Wouter van Ooijen

Comment: Check the datasheet instead of relying on your understanding. And check all such functional aspects (you mention the shift clock active edge). My (educated) guess is that an Arduino Uno won't be fast enough for those chips on any of the timing parameters.